# Swift+UIImageView: switch between two animation frame sequences?

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, uiimage, frames

Example of code for animation:

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
var jumpImages = ["Jump_1","Jump_2","Jump_3","Jump_4","Jump_5","Jump_6","Jump_7","Jump_8","Jump_9","Jump_10"]
if index == 1 {
     jumpImages = ["Jump_11","Jump_21","Jump_31","Jump_41","Jump_51","Jump_61","Jump_71","Jump_81","Jump_91","Jump_101"]
}
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in jumpImages{
        images.append(UIImage(named: image)!)
    }
    self.imageView.frame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y + 100.0
    self.imageView.animationImages = images
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
}
startAnimation(index: 0)
...
startAnimation(index: 1)
```

NOTE: Both `startAnimation` calls are in the main thread but not in the same run loop.

In my case I want to change `jumpImages` to another set of images. I should cancel the previous animation and start the new one but it looks like I set the last image in `jumpImages` sequence instead.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  You are animating your first set of images.  Then what?  You are canceling the animation?  Or changing the set of animationImages?  Or both?  Or starting a new one?  Please include the additional code and rephrase your question.

Comment: @drewster edited the question. Hope it is clear now. This code doesn't include stopping of the previous animation because I didn't find anything similar to workable solution.

Comment: @Sh_Khan try this code or similar and try to stop/cancel the first animation before starting the second one

Comment: Why not just hide/remove this image view and replace it by a different image view?

Comment: tried an it works , can you state the problem clearly

Comment: @Sh_Khan did you start the second animation when the first one is not finished yet. Or scheduled with this code but is not displayed yet?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I'm understanding your problem now -- from your statement, "*[...] but it looks like I set the last image in jumpImages sequence instead*," I think you mean that when you call **startAnimation(index: 1)**, you are seeing just the last frame of the index 0 animations, and none of the index 1 animations.

Assuming that is right, your problem here going to be a race condition.

When you call **startAnimation()** then second time with index 1, the first animation may or may not still be in progress.

The solution will be to call **self.imageView.stopAnimating()** before you change all the images and start the new animation.  The best practice would be to check the **imageView.isAnimating**  flag before you call it.  Something like this:

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
    var jumpImages = ["Jump_1","Jump_2","Jump_3","Jump_4","Jump_5","Jump_6","Jump_7","Jump_8","Jump_9","Jump_10"]
    if index == 1 {
         jumpImages = ["Jump_11","Jump_21","Jump_31","Jump_41","Jump_51","Jump_61","Jump_71","Jump_81","Jump_91","Jump_101"]
    }
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in jumpImages{
        images.append(UIImage(named: image)!)
    }

    if self.imageView.isAnimating {
        self.imageView.stopAnimating()
    }
    self.imageView.frame.origin.y = self.imageView.frame.origin.y + 100.0
    self.imageView.animationImages = images
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    self.imageView.startAnimating()
}
startAnimation(index: 0)
...
startAnimation(index: 1)
```

Also, since you're in a function and not within a closure, you can remove all those references to **self.**, which makes things a bit shorter:

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
    var jumpImages = ["Jump_1","Jump_2","Jump_3","Jump_4","Jump_5","Jump_6","Jump_7","Jump_8","Jump_9","Jump_10"]
    if index == 1 {
         jumpImages = ["Jump_11","Jump_21","Jump_31","Jump_41","Jump_51","Jump_61","Jump_71","Jump_81","Jump_91","Jump_101"]
    }
    var images = [UIImage]()
    for image in jumpImages{
        images.append(UIImage(named: image)!)
    }

    if imageView.isAnimating {
        imageView.stopAnimating()
    }
    imageView.frame.origin.y = imageView.frame.origin.y + 100.0
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 2.0
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()
}
startAnimation(index: 0)
...
startAnimation(index: 1)
```